# java file location background selector not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a background selector for a JFrame and everytime i try to set the background to the file it doesn't work

```
choose.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFileChooser openf = new JFileChooser();
                Component j = null;
                openf.showOpenDialog(j);
                File fl = openf.getSelectedFile();
                st = fl.getAbsolutePath();
                String string = st.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                path = string;
                SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(p).dispose();
                DFrame desktop = new DFrame();
                DFrame.l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path)));
                desktop.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: when i try to set the background it doesn't set to the path that was chosen it sets to the default background.